# How to limit git branch --format string length

Tags: text-processing, git

I have this `~/.gitconfig` alias:

`b = "!r() { count=10; git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate refs/heads --format='%(HEAD)%(color:bold green)%(committerdate:relative)|%(color:yellow)%(refname:short)|%(color:red)%(objectname:short)%(color:reset)|%(color:blue)%(subject)|%(color:magenta)%(authorname)%(color:reset)' --color=always --count=${count:=10} | column -c 10 -ts '|'; }; r"`

My issue with this function is that it formats the string based on the longest row, i.e. if I have a table with the following values (*This is not the output from `git branch --format`, just an example to illustrate `column` behavior*):

```
a, b, c
x, yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy, z
```

then it will look like

```
a, b                                                  , c
x, yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy, z
```

This is a good behavior which `column` is responsible to, however I want to trim the string length, so, for example, no column will be longer > 4:

```
a, b   , c
x, yyyy, z
```

I managed to add a piped `awk` to do something like that (used 25 chars):

`b = "!r() { count=10; git for-each-ref --sort=-committerdate refs/heads --format='%(HEAD)%(color:bold green)%(committerdate:relative)|%(color:yellow)%(refname:short)|%(color:red)%(objectname:short)%(color:reset)|%(color:    blue)%(subject)|%(color:magenta)%(authorname)%(color:reset)' --color=always --count=${count:=10} | column -c 10 -ts '|' | awk '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++){$i=substr($i,1,25)}; print $0}'; }; r"`

but it messes up the table :(

It also misbehaves with the `*` in the start of the current branch.

How can I fix this?

- I tried to install a newer version of `column` which should have a `-c` option to control width but I couldn't :( (downloaded from [here](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.37/) and then tried to `./configure && make install`. Didn't work as expected).
- Tried to format the function with `\` and newlines - didn't work. Must `gitconfig` functions look so ugly?

```bsh
$ git --version
git version 2.34.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have access to a `column` implementation that understands output width limitation, one way would be to implement the "column-building" algorithm in `awk`. However, implementing the logic - while straighforward - adds quite a bit to the length of your `gitconfig` function:

```
awk -F'|' -v maxw=4 '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {l=length($i); if (l>maxw) l=maxw; if (l>mw[i]) mw[i]=l; lines[NR]=$0}}
    END{for (j=1;j<=NR;j++) {n=split(lines[j],f,/\|/); for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {printf("%*s%s",mw[i],substr(f[i],1,maxw),i==n?ORS:OFS)}}}'
```

As you can see, this `awk` program splits the input on the `|` (which is what you stated to be the actual output of the `git branch` command).

- For each line it iterates over all fields and stores the maximum field width in an array `mw` for each column, but limited to the maximum width as specified in the variable `maxw`.
- It then stores the "original" content of each line (including the original field separators) in a buffering array `lines`.
- At end-of-input, it iterates over the `lines` buffer and splits the line again at the `|` into an array `f`. For each entry of `f`, it prints at most `maxw` characters of the field via `printf`, where the desired field width is taken from the `mw` array for the respective column.

For your example (but assuming the actual `|`-separation instead of the `,` you showed), the output would be:

```
a    b c
x yyyy z
```

Comment: Yeah, now I see. Thanks! however, integrating this into my gitconfig is not working. I guess I need to escape something here, but can't find what (other than escaping `"` which didn't fix the issue)